# Obfuscated PHP using grunt-hazy has syntax error

Tags: php, gruntjs, obfuscation

I'm getting to know Grunt, trying to do some obfuscation of my test php file.

Here's the original code, just a simple hello world

```
<?php
echo 'hello world';
```

Obfuscated using grunt-hazy:

```
<?php eval("?>".base64_decode("PD9waHANCmVjaG8gJ2hlbGxvIHdvcmxkJzs=")."<?"); ?>
```

And the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in D:\Projects\Grunter\hazed\index.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 2
```

Here's my Gruntfile

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        hazy: {
            php: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '',
                dest: 'hazed',
                src: [ '*.php' ]
            }
        },
        watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: ['*.php'],
                tasks: ['hazy']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-hazy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it a bug with the plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the decoded code that's ran through eval, you get this.

```
?><?php
echo 'hello world';<?
```

So as you can see, you close a PHP tag, then it opens a new one, echoes some text, then tries to open another tag without closing the first one.

If you try adding a closing PHP tag in your test script, my guess is it will work fine.

Comment: Didn't think of that, thank you! I will accept your answer when SO allows me to

Comment: Not a problem :). I guess it's because the grunt-hazed doesn't check for match opening/closing tags, which is probably the right way to do things.

Comment: His program worked before he ran the obfuscator.  After, it didn't work.  That's a buggy obfuscator.